# "The" is used to refer the specificty. Which particularity is indicated by "the" in the given sentence?

Tags: usage, definite-article

There is a protein in our body called Intrinsic factor.

So, if there is a sentence - "The" intrinsic factor is a glycoprotein.  By putting "the" before intrinsic, the sense of the sentence is like a particular factor which is intrinsic. So, by putting "the" before intrinsic, the specificity is on "intrinsic" or the whole, "intrinsic factor"?

[Link](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK546655/) from where I have studied.

Comment: Hi Meera, there is no such phrase on the page you linked to.

Comment: In above sentence, putting *the* before intrinsic factor is inapt.

Comment: @Joachim What phrase do you mean? *the intrinsic factor* appears twice in the article although not in the exact wording of the question. However the OP does say **if there is a sentence** not **there is a sentence** so the question does not refer directly to the specific wording of the article.

Comment: @Sam As I pointed out in my comment to Joachim, "**the** intrinsic factor" occurs twice in the article, so it would appear to be apt in some circumstances.

Comment: In the link, it is written that - The intrinsic factor is a glycoprotein.

Comment: @PeterJennings I assumed the first sentence of the question body was a quote (it could have been used as an introduction to their question, but it doesn't make sense to me either way).

Comment: As [*this usage chart*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=secretion+of+intrinsic+factor%2Csecretion+of+the+intrinsic+factor&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) for ***secretion of** [**the**] **intrinsic factor*** clearly shows, people today almost ***never*** include the article when referring to the protein. They weren't so sure what to do a century ago, when the name first started to be used, but *everyone* is singing from the same hymn-sheet today.

Answer (score 1):

I do not claim to understand the article to which you link, but **intrinsic factor** appears to be a noun phrase so it can be used on its own, preceded by **the** or **an** without change of meaning or emphasis.

Again I know very little about physiology but there appears to be only one *intrinsic factor* as, in the first line of the article, it is referred to as "The intrinsic factor …" which implies there isn't another one, unlike a blood clotting factors of which there are 13.

Comment: So, if I put any article before a noun phrase, it applies to all words in a noun phrase ? And also, noun phrase behave as a single entity?

Comment: @Meera Yes, exactly. There are bound to be exceptions which other contributors will point out, but in general a noun phrase acts as a single entity with regard to how it is used in the sentence. For example singular v plural "intrinsic factor … **it** …" , but "blood clotting factors … **they**   … " and "**the** intrinsic factor" but "**a** blood clotting factor" (there are more than one known BCFs). In other words pronouns, definite and indefinite articles, gender specific wording (but obviously not in this case) and so on.